# Is It a common way to say "to be" as "[tuː][buː]"?

Tags: pronunciation

I just notice the speaker pronounce "to be" as "[tuː][buː]" in the sentence.
I think "to be" could be pronounced as "[tuːbi]" or [tu:bə]. why in the audio the speak pronounce "to be" as "[tuːbuː]"?

I extract the "to be" fragment from the "audio" for making sure.

my questions are:

is it [tu:bu] in the audio?

is It a common way to say "to be" as "[tuː][buː]"?

as an English learner.I found it not easy to recognize the words in this situation.

is any way help me to handle it easier?

- [**full audio** (Google Drive)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aF3S6IJ2x0jszNgGz4KY5BznNXgnLaco/view?usp=sharing)

  > But deep learning is also enabling brand new products and businesses and ways of helping people to be created
- [**to be fragment audio** (Google Drive)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19BkDAfrnf4FBeyE6J8eltG3KGxgFOrAr/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: It doesn't sound like a native speaker to me. The word "be" is not pronounced properly there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there's no point in trying to analyze how some random non-native Anglophone pronounces English words. Learn English from ***Anglophones**!*

Comment: He says 'to be' very quickly and with an indeterminate vowel sound.

Comment: Also, AI has *really* advanced beyond even the wildest expectations if it is "helping people to be created".

Comment: Second time we've heard this speaker [& sentence] in a question here. Try not to use this as your yardstick. It's hard to decide whether he's even native. he's certainly not a professional broadcaster. It's all too rushed & panicky. Just move on to another speaker. Forget this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree with the comments you have received that dismiss this speaker as "non-native". There is nothing in his accent that make me think he is non-native, although I admit his accent does sound quite 'muddled' - some words sound an American English speaker, some sound British English, possibly even with a little Scottish accent in there, too, but it is difficult to be certain with such a short clip. Having a mixed accent can in some cases indicate a non-native speaker, as some people learn languages from TV and movies which present them with a variety of accents; however, it can also just be evidence that a person has moved around between places with differing accents and picked up ways of saying certain things in different places. In any case, you've gone to a lot of trouble to present the audio clips and I think your question deserves an answer.

I don't hear anything too different or unusual in the way this speaker pronounces the word "be". It is simply an unstressed vowel because his words are rolling into each other (another sign of a native speaker, unlike learners who are more likely to over-pronounce individual words). It sounds like a correct pronunciation (/ˈbiː/) to me, just not as pronounced as if it were Shakespeare's "*to be, or not to be*".

Comment: I'd wager 100 points that the voice doesn't even belong to a human.  :-)