# what make "and I" sounds like "ne" and "that" sounds like "de" to me?

Tags: pronunciation

According to the Wikipedia introduction, the speaker is a British-American computer scientist and  an adjunct professor at Stanford University. So I think he is pronunciation is rather native, at least can be easily understand by native English speaker.

I am an non-native english learner. His unstressed syllable pronunciation (not one his pronunciation, but also others) confused me because some words are pronounced very different to what I learned.

Please listen to the audio and guess what was the speaker saying.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t8AIcgNnBQy5OE1ZdgX71b0ZCMedEe_G/view?usp=sharing

the transcription is

> and I hope that you will play a big role in the creation of this AI-powered society.

What I heard is

> ne hope de you will play a big role in the creation of this AI-powered society.

My question is:
What makes "and I" sound like "ne" and "that" sound like "de" to me?

I think the question is different between the question :
[Is It a common way to say "to be" as "[tuː][buː]"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/344073/is-it-a-common-way-to-say-to-be-as-tu%cb%90bu%cb%90)

Although they are from same accent issue but different words.but to me,I don't really care if his accent is perfect or not. what I care is the reason native speak can understand it but it strange to me. although his accent is a bit different. but it still share same mechanism with very native English pronunciation.

eg. **and** can be unstressed as "an" or "n".I think the rule is same between the accent of the speaker and native english speaker.

In other words. I don't intent to discuss the accent .I'd like talk about the unstressed word rule itself.It's just a basis question. don't think it in a higher level.

Because I don't think I can learn how to unstress "and" from how to unstress "to". So they are two questions

Comment: I've voted to close, as this really is the same issue as your previous question but with different words.  This speaker is talking fast, he has a slightly odd accent, he slurs a few of his words and he "underpronounces" others. He doesn't sound like a recording for a TOEFL test, he sounds like an intelligent professor talking about a subject that he understands well and not trying to make it easy for a non-native listener.

Comment: Moreover the recording is of mediocre quality.  The reduction of "And" to "n" and "I" to "ah" are common and standard in some dialects.  The word "that" has had it's final "t" lost so it becomes 'tha"  Again, this is normal.  Indeed the only word that sounds odd to me is "powered".   So I hear "'n' a-hope tha *you*..."  The word "you" receives emphatic stress so isn't reduced.

Comment: And the only solution is to learn to listen to a wider range of speakers in a diversity of contexts.  Don't try to listen for individual sounds when you are listening for comprehension. That is like trying to listen to a Beethoven symphony and hear the individual notes of each instrument - you will miss what is important.

Comment: Here in the UK, the clip refuses to play in Chrome and suggests the use of additional download software. But it will play in Edge and Brave (a less well known browser).  I hear "'nd I hope that you ..."

Comment: Just to comment on his accent.  Andrew Ng was born in the UK, to Hong Kong immigrant parents. He spent time growing up in Singapore and has spent a considerable time in the USA.  All of these influences are present in his accent. So it isn't an RP British accent. The Hong Kong and Singapore forms of English underlie his accent, and the American/Californian layer is present too.

Comment: Plays for me in linux chrome in the UK It is a raw mp3 file, so you'll need an mp3 player library somewhere

Comment: @JamesK when I was a boy, a new flavour of potato crisps (US 'chips') emerged in the UK, which appeared on the packets as `Cheese 'n' onion`. For some reason it annoyed me and still does a bit (I don't like them). A cursory web search just now seems to show that, for all major brands, an ampersand has taken the place of the `'n'` - I'm not sure why.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - What about _rock 'n' roll_?

Comment: @KateBunting - is that _rock & roll_ these days?

Comment: @JamesK - +1 for Linux (plays in Chrome on Debian here)

Comment: @PeterJennings - plays for me in Google Chrome on Windows 11 and in Debian Bullseye. Also Firefox, but not Opera

Comment: @PeterJennings - it did play in Opera, it just took a while buffering.